# List of pages in Kentico

Tags: c#, asp.net, content-management-system, kentico

In my site on Kentico I have a page that contain a list of links to another pages. Let's say articles. I have a repeater on my aspx page and code below that fills it. 
It works but I think it's a kind of hack. Is there a better approach to do it?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dataSource = DocumentHelper.GetDocuments("custom.CustomPressRelease")
        .Select(x => new
        {
            Link = GetUrl(x),
            PublishFrom = x.GetValue("DateIssued"),
            Title = x.GetValue("ContentTitle"),
            Teaser = x.GetValue("TeaserText"),
            GeoCoverage = x.GetValue("GeoCoverage")
        })
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.PublishFrom);

    Repeater.DataSource = dataSource;
    Repeater.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No hack about what you posted.  In the [documentation here](https://docs.kentico.com/api10/content-management/pages#Pages-Pagemanagement) and [ObjectQuery 
 documentation here](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/custom-development/retrieving-database-data-using-objectquery-api) it also shows another way to get your information:

```
// Creates an instance of the Tree provider
TreeProvider tree = new TreeProvider(MembershipContext.AuthenticatedUser);

// Gets the published version of pages stored under the "/Articles/" path
// The pages are retrieved from the Dancing Goat site and in the "en-us" culture
var pages = tree.SelectNodes()
    .ClassNames("custom.CustomPressRelease")
    .Path("/Articles/", PathTypeEnum.Children)
    .WhereLike("DocumentName", "Coffee%")
    .Columns("NodeAliasPath", "DateIssued", "ContentTitle", "TeaserText", "GeoCoverage")
    .OnSite("DancingGoat")
    .Culture("en-us");
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there a significant performance difference between my and your decision?

Comment: No. EXCEPT you're not specifying the columns so your query will bring back 180+ columns of data whereas mine will bring back the 4 I specified plus maybe 10 additional that are needed for system reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Well, what makes you think it's a hack? This is how you do it programmatically. If you wanted to achieve the same thing using the [portal engine](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/developing-websites/developing-websites-using-the-portal-engine) you would add the repeater web part, set up its filter and transformation and you'd be done. Or you could use the basic repeater web part and bind it to the pages data source.

You can also combine the ASPX template + Portal Engine approaches - you can still have your ASPX page and use the built-in web parts (repeater, basic repeater, data sources...) They're standard ASCX controls. You just need to set them up correctly. It shouldn't be a problem, the properties are usually 1:1 with what you see in the portal engine.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes, I have to do it programmatically. I'm a new one in Kentico, that a reason why I thought it is a kind of hack. I see, this is an acceptable way.